# Writing a projective scheme as a union of irreducible subschemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, primary-decomposition

Suppose $i: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a projective scheme, over some field $k$ (I'm not sure if *algebraically closed* is necessary here). So $X$ comes together with an ideal sheaf and a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{I}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \rightarrow i_* \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow 0.$$
Topologically $X$ consists of finitely many irreducible components. I would like to know if it is always possible to write $X$ as a *scheme-theoretic* union of irreducible subschemes $X_i \hookrightarrow X$, i.e. $\mathcal{I}_X = \bigcap_i \mathcal{I}_{X_i}$.

I think this works if $X$ is reduced, then one can just take the irreducible components together with the reduced structure as $X_i$, and $\mathcal{I}_X = \bigcap_i \mathcal{I}_{X_i}$, because the intersection of radical ideals is again radical, and two radical ideals with the same vanishing locus are equal, by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Does this have anything to do with primary decomposition? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition#Geometric_interpretation) states that there is some scheme theoretic interpretation of primary decomposition, but suppose $\mathcal{I}_X$ is the intersection of non-primary ideals, then why should it be possible to write it as the intersection of primary ideals?

Comment: It's a theorem that in a noetherian ring every ideal has a primary decomposition (c.f., Atiyah-MacDonald, Thm 7.13), which deals with the case of affine schemes. I think there is a similar result for graded rings in Eisenbud, which would mean the same is true for projective schemes.

Comment: Yeah I'm still trying to figure out primary ideals. Is it true that an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$ is primary if and only if $\text{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})$ is irreducible?

Comment: Yes, I think that follows from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541943

Comment: I don't think this is true anymore :D See the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092532/primary-ideals-are-those-whose-quotient-has-irreducible-prime-spectrum), and the counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728363/whats-the-motivation-of-the-definition-of-primary-ideals/728535#728535).

Comment: But...you're not using the definition of primary, just a strictly weaker property.

Comment: Correctly. So there are ideals for which $A/\mathfrak{a}$ has irreducible spectrum, but $\mathfrak{a}$ is not primary.

Comment: Ah, I see. Only one implication is true. Thanks!

Comment: For reduced schemes, the minimal decomposition is unique and does give you the irreducible components on the nose, as you said. For non-reduced, you'll have to look at the minimal primes in such decomposition to see the irreducible components; the other factors will correspond to embedded components, and are not unique. As @André3000 mentions, that a primary decomposition always exists is a theorem for any finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring. And clearly primary decomposition determines a scheme theoretic decomposition. I'm not sure if your question cuts deeper than this.

Comment: As an aside, the point of primary decomposition is, I guess, that the embedded components will not only be irreducible, but will only have nilpotents, as pointed out in the questions you link to.