# Projective subscheme as union of its components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

This is the same question [Writing a projective scheme as a union of irreducible subschemes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092333/writing-a-projective-scheme-as-a-union-of-irreducible-subschemes) but this was not clearly answered: if I have $Z \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ a projective scheme, I can associate to that its ideal sheaf $I_Z$.

I've tried to prove that there exists irreducible  closed subscheme $Z_i$ such that $I_Z=I_{Z_1}+\dots I_{Z_n}$, but I was not able to do that.

Locally on affine open sets we know how to do that. I tried to gluw what I got on open affines but because of the lack of uniqueness of primary decomposition I did not know how to make that.

If it can be any help, one can assume $Z$ to be equidimensional as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Please improve your question by adding what you have tried and where you're stuck. Where did your proof break down?